# Get number of likes of the url (facebook like button)

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

My websites contains a lot of thumbnails. I want to put a like button in every thumbnail. But is there any to get the number likes in that button? The idea is I want to sort those thumbnails according to the likes count. So that thumbnail having largest likes count will be on top. The website is made using php, it would be great if i can get that count in php.

Comment: SQL statement should be `ORDER BY likes DESC` and then just put the number of likes (or abbreviated number of likes) below the thumbnail or wherever.

Comment: @Companjo He says "Facebook-like" so I'm guessing he doesn't actually want the Facebook "Like" button.

Comment: I want the Facebook like button.  Because when someone likes it goes to their Facebook too